# bash does not recognize executable Perl script

Tags: bash, perl, executable

I have a very mysterious problem with bash and/or perl. I'll try to describe the behaviour.

Running a perl script via

```
./perlscript.pl
```

gives me a permission denied message.

(I am the owner of the file and the path to it -from my home dir *and* the file contains `#!/usr/bin/perl` *and* is executable `-rwxr-xr-x` )

Running the script like this:

```
perl perlscript.pl
```

is ok...

Can anyone please help me fix my bash? Thank you

---

```
$ which perl
/usr/bin/perl

$ head -1 file.pl | od -c
0000000 # ! / u s r / b i n / p e r l \n
0000020
```

Comment: Does the file have DOS newlines?

Comment: Did you mean to say `!#/usr/bin/perl` or was that a typo? The correct directive is `#!/usr/bin/perl` or better `#!/usr/bin/env perl`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions  1.the file does not have DOS new lines (I tried egrepping for \r\n).   2. I meant to say #! . Thank you. I'll correct my post

Comment: what does `which perl` return ?

Comment: @Karlo, egrep won't find `\r\n` because grep is a line oriented tool (grep will not ever find `\n`). Try: `head -1 file.pl | od -c`

Comment: @Hunter `which perl` returns `/usr/bin/perl` @glenn your command returns: `0000000   #   !   /   u   s   r   /   b   i   n   /   p   e   r   l  \n
0000020`

Comment: Run `cat -vet perlscript.pl | head -1` and post the result please.

Comment: Also, what happens when you run `/usr/bin/perl -e ''`

Comment: @DVK [cat output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m0sj3rbvlk4zxgs/cat_vet?dl=0)  and `/usr/bin/perl -e ''` does not return anything... thanks again

Comment: @Karlo : directory permission is missing 'x' , what is  l  -lda  .

Comment: what gives ldd /usr/bin/perl ?

Comment: strace ./perlscript.pl vs strace perl ./perlscript.pl ... to find differences

Comment: once again, thanks everyone for the effort, the problem has been identified (answer below)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is the filesystem where `perlscript.pl` is located mounted with the `noexec` flag?

Assuming you're on Linux, `cat /proc/mounts` and look for `noexec` on the line with the appropriate filesystem.

The `noexec` flag prevents anyone from calling [exec](http://man.cx/exec%283%29) on a file located on that filesystem (which is what bash does when you do `./perlscript.pl`).  But `perl perlscript.pl` calls exec on `/usr/bin/perl`, which then opens `perlscript.pl` for reading.

Files on a `noexec`-mounted filesystem can still *have* execute permission, they just can't make use of it.

Comment: i was thinking to the very same, i tested it with a localy mounted filesystem and bingo : if as root i mount -o loop,noexec empty mounted => as my user : cd mounted ./perlscript.pl fails, . AND file is still visible with +x rights... now waiting for the confirmation from @Karlo...

Comment: Yes, thats is the problem. I moved my home directory to a mounted storage space and the 'cat /proc/mounts' has noexec next to it... thank you!!